# Can't use parameterized SQL Statements with Node.js and Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parameterized-query

I've been banging my head with this since last night. When I add parameters to the sql, it doesn't work.

```
var findOne = function(username, cb) {
    pg.connect(pgURL, function(err, client, done) {
        var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [username]);
        done();

        query.on('row', function(row) {
            cb(err, row);
        });
    });
};
```

However, if I do an SQL statement without parameterization it works just fine.

```
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'foobar'");
```

Also, doing a console.log(query), right after done(), yields the following:

```
13:48:00 web.1  | { domain: null,
13:48:00 web.1  |   _events: null,
13:48:00 web.1  |   _maxListeners: 10,
13:48:00 web.1  |   name: undefined,
13:48:00 web.1  |   text: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1',
13:48:00 web.1  |   values: [ '{"username":"foobar"}' ],
13:48:00 web.1  |   callback: undefined,
13:48:00 web.1  |   _result: 
13:48:00 web.1  |    { command: null,
13:48:00 web.1  |      rowCount: null,
13:48:00 web.1  |      oid: null,
13:48:00 web.1  |      rows: [],
13:48:00 web.1  |      fields: [],
13:48:00 web.1  |      _parsers: [],
13:48:00 web.1  |      RowCtor: null },
13:48:00 web.1  |   _addedFields: false,
13:48:00 web.1  |   _canceledDueToError: false }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your username variable appears to be a Javascript object with key username and value foobar. Try `username.username` to reference just the value.

Alternatively, I highly recommend the ORM Sequelize, which sits on top of pg. Take a look here: http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#usage-raw-queries

Comment: Great catch. Thanks, that's exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure username is a string? Try doing `username.toString()`.

Comment: adding username.toString(), did not change results. I've added the output of console.log(query) (which I added right after done()) to the original post.